# Variable provider names $ and ^ have a value of Clear-Host

Tags: powershell

If I run the statement `Get-ChildItem Variable:` I get the following as the beginning of the output. What does this mean when the Names `$` and `^` have values of `Clear-Host` ?

[image]

Comment: They are automatic variables. `$$` is the last token received. `$^` is the first token of the last line received. `$?` is if the last command was successful or not.

Comment: See [`about_Automatic_Variables`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables).

Comment: @mklement0 thank you! knowing that they are referred to as _automatic_ variables to be able to find help was the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$`, `?`, and `^` are names of [Automatic Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7). You can retrieve their values like any other variable using `Get-Variable` or prefixing with `$`.

- `$$` prints the last token in the last line received by the session
- `$?` prints `True` (equal to `$true`) if the execution status of the last command was successful. `False` is printed otherwise.
- `$^` prints the first token in the last line received by the session.

As to what comprises a token, [About Parsing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-7) highlights the PowerShell command parser. Expression vs. argument mode of parsing determines what is considered a token.

Answer (score 1):

[`Get-Help about_Automatic_Variables`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables)

> $$
>  Contains the last token in the last line received by the
> session.
>
> …
>
> $^
>  Contains the first token in the last line received by the
> session.

Comment: Thanks. Similar to the start and end anchors within regex